# Span and Lights in a circle

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I am pretty new to linear algebra so some of the stuff I say might be complete off its mark and I would appreciate if you would correct me on that.

We had a question today on 5 lights in a circle, each connected to a switch. Each switch toggles the corresponding bulb and its two neighbours. There are 32 possible combinations of lights and we were given the question of whether starting from all lights off we are able to get to every single combination.

My initial thought is to make vectors for each of the five switches and then determine the span. However I believe this is impossible because although theoretically since the vectors span every combination it should be possible but i am unable to make lights that are double off or double on causing my only idea to fall flat on its face. I have no clue anymore on what I should be trying to reach this answer other than physically testing each combination.

Comment: Question is unclear: specifically, this "When switched would toggle the state of the light bulb above and directly aside from the switch"

Comment: From the all off configuration. The first switch flipped is always going to create a "double off" configuration. Flipping 4 different switches are always going to create a "double on" configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial idea is right, but we have to deal with the vectors over the field $\Bbb F_2$ of the residues modulo $2$. Enumerate the bulbs by residues modulo $5$ and for each such residue $i$ let $v_i$ be a vector corresponding to toggle of $i$-th bulb and its two neighbours. To show that the span of $v_i$’s generates all possible combinations of lights from the total darkness, :-) it suffices to show that for each residue $i$ modulo $5$ the span contains a vector $e_i$ corresponding to toggle of single $i$-th bulb. And this is true, because $e_i=v_{i-2}+v_i+v_{i+2}$.